# List of index out of range in file handling

Tags: python

I am new at making a program for a Natural Language. I am having an error using Chunk Reader. The error that I am getting is list of index out of range. This my written code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus.reader import ConllChunkCorpusReader
num_string = []
sen = int(input("Enter how many lines of text: ")) 
f = open("D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob", "w")
for i in range (0,sen):
    element = str(input(str(i + 1) + ". "))
    (num_string.append(element))
for name in num_string:
    f.write("%s\n" %(name))
f = open("D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob", "r")
conllreader = ConllChunkCorpusReader('D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob', r'.*\.iob', ('NP','VP', 'PP'))
print ("CONLLREADER CHUNKED WORDS")
print(conllreader.chunked_words('D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob'))
print ("==================================")
print ("CONLLREADER CHUNKED SENTS")
print(conllreader.chunked_sents('D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob'))
print ("==================================")
print ("CONLLREADER IOB WORDS")
print(conllreader.iob_words('D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob'))
print ("==================================")
print ("CONLLREADER IOB SENTS")
print(conllreader.iob_words('D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob'))
print ("==================================")
```

So, when I want 10 lines, I should input 10 times but after inputting, I am having an error that says list of index out of range and obviously, the conllreader is not working and that's where the error started. I am also using a file handling.

conll.iob file:

Mr. NNP B-NP

Meador NNP I-NP

had VBD B-VP

been VBN I-VP

executive JJ B-NP

vice NN I-NP

president NN I-NP

of IN B-PP

Balcor NNP B-NP

. . O

(NOTE: There is no space between the text, I just made a space so it will be clearer).
The file text is my sample. So in my input for lines is 10. And again, I am having an error about having list index out of range.

Answer (score 0):

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus.reader import ConllChunkCorpusReader
num_string = []
sen = int(input("Enter how many lines of text: ")) 
f = open("D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob", "w")
try:
  for i in range (0,sen):
    element = str(input(str(i + 1) + ". "))
    (num_string.append(element))
except Exception as e:
  pass
for name in num_string:
    f.write("%s\n" %(name))
f = open("D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob", "r")
conllreader = ConllChunkCorpusReader('D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob', r'.*\.iob', ('NP','VP', 'PP'))
print ("CONLLREADER CHUNKED WORDS")
print(conllreader.chunked_words('D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob'))
print ("==================================")
print ("CONLLREADER CHUNKED SENTS")
print(conllreader.chunked_sents('D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob'))
print ("==================================")
print ("CONLLREADER IOB WORDS")
print(conllreader.iob_words('D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob'))
print ("==================================")
print ("CONLLREADER IOB SENTS")
print(conllreader.iob_words('D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob'))
print ("==================================")
```

Comment: This is not working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Please Check it now. I think it will work perfect.**

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus.reader import ConllChunkCorpusReader
num_string = []
sen = int(input("Enter how many lines of text: ")) 
f = open("D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob", "w")
try:
  for i in range (0,sen):
    element = str(input(str(i + 1) + ". "))
    (num_string.append(element))
except Exception as e:
  pass
for name in num_string:
    f.write("%s\n" %(name))
f = open("D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob", "r")
conllreader = ConllChunkCorpusReader('D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob', r'.*\.iob', ('NP','VP', 'PP'))
print ("CONLLREADER CHUNKED WORDS")
print(conllreader.chunked_words('D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob'))
print ("==================================")
print ("CONLLREADER CHUNKED SENTS")
print(conllreader.chunked_sents('D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob'))
print ("==================================")
print ("CONLLREADER IOB WORDS")
print(conllreader.iob_words('D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob'))
print ("==================================")
print ("CONLLREADER IOB SENTS")
print(conllreader.iob_words('D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob'))
print ("==================================")
```